# Getting an Ajax response from Zend Framework Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework, response

I'm doing an Ajax request on one of my views to a Controller but I am unable to send back a response to the Ajax method. In the snippet below, I am trying to send the word 'hellopanda' back but in the alert message, I'll get data as an object.

**View :**

```
$.ajax({  

      type: "POST",  
      url: "localhost/some-activity",
      data: dataString, 
      success: function(data) { 
              alert( "Data is: " + data);
          //do something with data
      },
      error: function(data){
               alert( "Data is: " + data);
        //do something with data 
          },
      onComplete: function(){

          }
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function someActivityAction(){

   //do stuff

   echo "hellopanda";

 }
```

I'm pretty sure the echo is the problem. Any insights on to how to do a proper response to the view would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your url is  `"localhost/some-activity"` change that to `"localhost/someactivity"`
in your action

```
public function someactivityAction(){

//do stuff

echo "hellopanda";

exit;

}
```

if you want to return an array make sure to encode like

```
echo $this->_helper->json($yourarray);exit;
```

and your ajax will be like this

```
$.ajax({  

      type: "POST",  
      url: "localhost/someactivity",
      data: dataString, 
      dataType: 'json', //if you are returning array
      success: function(data) { 
           for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                 alert(data[i]['yourindexofarray']);
              }
      },
      error: function(data){
               alert( "Data is: " + data);
        //do something with data 
          },
      onComplete: function(){

          }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how to get the variables from the ajax call in the Zend Controller? I need to interact in PHP with the `data` sent from my ajax.